Do any reliable recreations of Jesus' Aramaic sayings exist?
Do any reliable recreations of Jesus' Aramaic sayings exist? As far as I know, the Peshittas are fourth-century translations from Greek, and much of the language seems to have evolved over those centuries.

While most scholars do agree with the OP that the Peshitta derives from the Greek NT, the Syrian Orthodox tradition understands the relationship to be the other way around. In any case, George Lamsa's translation of the NT remains the go-to version for comparing the Greek versions of Jesus' sayings to the Aramaic. I still have copy and consult it occasionally.
I have a recollection of hearing him speak 50 years ago (although it may be a recollection of someone telling me about this!) For what it's worth, I do recall his idea that it wasn't a camel that had to go through the eye of a needle (Matthew 19:24), but a rope. This question has been discussed on this site here.
In terms of what the OP is looking for this may be the best resource: Lamsa's compendium of biblical idioms deciphered in light of his linguistic expertise.
